# What are the different approaches for deploying DB changes using TFS 2015?

Tags: sql-server-2012, tfs-2015, devops

Currently, we are manual running DB scripts (SQL Server 2012) outside of our CI/CD deployment. What are ways (including toolsets) can we automate deployment of DB changes using TFS 2015 Update 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are really two approaches here, both of which work with TFS. Really TFS just facilitates the execution of any scripting that you will use to update your database, including your custom, handcrafted scripts.

There is the state based approach, which uses a comparison technology to look at your VCS/dev/test/staging database and compare this to production. [SQL Source Control](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/) and the DLM Automation Suite from Redgate Software does this, as do other comparison tools. What you would do is use a command line or programmatic interface to set your source and target, capture the output and then use this as an artifact in your release process. I might include a review of the artifact as a scripting choice in your flow.

Note, there are some problems that State based comparisons don't do well with. Renames, splits, merges, data movement, a few others. Some comparison tools have ways around this, some do not. Be aware this may be an issue. If you have a more mature database, perhaps not, but you should consider this. SQL Source Control allows custom migration scripts, which can handle these issues.

The other approach is a script runner or migration strategy where each change you make to a dev database is captured as an ordered script and a framework executes these in order, if they are needed. This is preferred by some people since you can see exactly what code will be executed at dev and deployment time. [ReadyRoll](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/readyroll/) from Redgate Software, Liquibase, Rails Migrations, DBUp, FlywayDB, all use this strategy.

Neither of these is better or worse. Both work, both have pros and cons, but really the choice comes down to your comfort level and preference.

Disclosure: I work for Redgate Software.

Answer (score 1):

If deploy DB changes just mean using SQL Server Database Projects (.sqlproj files) with Team Foundation Build in Team Foundation Server.

There are several ways can achieve this:

- Use MSBuild task with some arguments to publish your SQL project
  during build.
- Add a deploy target in your sqlproj file,run the target after build
  completes.
- Or  add a "Batch Script" step in your build
  definition to run "SqlPackage.exe" to publish the `.dacpac` file.

More details  please refer to this blog: [Deploying SSDT During Local and Server Build](http://mohamedradwan.com/2014/11/06/deploying-ssdt-during-local-and-server-build/) .

---

As for using TFS2015, you can also try to use **[SQL Server Database Deployment](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/sql-server-database-deployment)** task.

> Use this task to deploy a SQL Server database to an existing SQL
>   Server instance. The task uses a [DACPAC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ee210546.aspx) and [SqlPackage.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080.aspx), which
>   provides fine-grained control over database creation and upgrades.